# Meteor.js Show sum of the selected options in form

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hi I have an application form that includes a select list. Data from the select list are stored in the data collection.

I would like to show the sum of the selected options attributable to each choice found in the form field.

Does anyone know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification of the Leaderboard example to show this: [meteorpad example here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/SSFDi69bSsdNr7DTN/Leaderboard)

```
<template name="leaderboard">
  <select multiple class="leaderboard">
    <option value="20">Grace Hopper: 20</option>
    <option value="15">Carl Friedrich Gauss: 15</option>
    <option value="15">Nikola Teslar: 15</option>
    <option value="5">Ada Lovelace: 5</option>
    <option value="5">Claude Shannon: 5</option>
    <option value="0">Marie Curie: 0</option>
  </select>
  <h1>  Total:  {{total}}  </h1>
</template>
```

$('option:selected') is used to find the selected items:

```
Template.leaderboard.onRendered(function(){
  Session.set('Total', 'Select (multiple) scientists to see the total of their points');
});

Template.leaderboard.events({
  'click': function () {
    Session.set('Total',  _.reduce( 
         $('option:selected').map(function(i, opt){return Number(opt.value);}), 
         function(a, b){ return a + b; }, 0));
  }
});

Template.leaderboard.helpers({
  total: function(){
    return Session.get('Total');
  },
});
```

Comment: The comments section is not where you ask new questions.  However what you are asking is a straightforward map-reduce problem.  Try searching for map-reduce in javascript, if you can't find a solution post a new question.